How fix Kafka error The producer attempted to update a transaction while another concurrent operation on the same transaction was ongoing?
The work process is as follows: the consumer receives a task, we create a producer, create a transaction, a unique transaction id is required, we do all sorts of calculations and do an offset and a commit. Out of 150t operations, there may be 5-10 such errors.
Maybe my problem is that I create a new producer for each iteration?
